# How to return an instance that borrows local data

Tags: rust

I have the following code:

```rust
fn prepare_sut_and_stuff<'a>() -> (ExistingProjectInitializer<'a>, AppConfigManager, PathBuf, tempfile::TempDir) {
    let base_dir = tempfile::tempdir().unwrap();
    let file_path = base_dir.path().join("config.json");
    let mut file = File::create(&file_path).unwrap();
    write!(file, "{{\"projects\":[]}}").unwrap();

    let config_manager = AppConfigManager::new(file_path).unwrap();

    let sut = ExistingProjectInitializer::new(&config_manager);

    (sut, config_manager, file_path, base_dir)
}
```

It's a function in my test module. This function is a helper that is supposed to prepare a bunch of things that some of my unit tests need.

As you can see, in the function I'm creating an instance of `AppConfigManager` and I'm using a reference to it to create an `ExistingProjectInitializer`. I need to return these instances (and some more data), because they are useful for the test methods.

The code does not compile, because I'm returning an instance of `ExistingProjectInitializer` that has a reference to an `AppConfigManager` that was created in the function's scope.

Here's the compiler's message:

```
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing local variable `config_manager`
   --> src/project_init/existing.rs:121:9
    |
119 |         let sut = ExistingProjectInitializer::new(&config_manager);
    |                                                   --------------- `config_manager` is borrowed here
120 |
121 |         (sut, config_manager, file_path, base_dir)
    |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
```

How can I change that function to do what it's supposed to do and compile?
I feel like I should use some smart pointer. I tried boxing the `config_manager`, but that didn't help in anything, probably I did it wrong:

```rust
fn prepare_sut_and_stuff<'a>() -> (ExistingProjectInitializer<'a>, Box<AppConfigManager>, PathBuf, tempfile::TempDir) {
    let base_dir = tempfile::tempdir().unwrap();
    let file_path = base_dir.path().join("config.json");
    let mut file = File::create(&file_path).unwrap();
    write!(file, "{{\"projects\":[]}}").unwrap();

    let config_manager = Box::new(AppConfigManager::new(file_path).unwrap());

    let sut = ExistingProjectInitializer::new(&config_manager);

    (sut, config_manager, file_path, base_dir)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need the `AppConfigManager` in the calling context, you could instead make it so it is owned by the `ExistingProjectInitializer` and accessible as a field.

The function would then look like this:

```
fn prepare_sut_and_stuff() -> (ExistingProjectInitializer, PathBuf, tempfile::TempDir) {
    let base_dir = tempfile::tempdir().unwrap();
    let file_path = base_dir.path().join("config.json");
    let mut file = File::create(&file_path).unwrap();
    write!(file, "{{\"projects\":[]}}").unwrap();

    let config_manager = AppConfigManager::new(file_path).unwrap();

    let sut = ExistingProjectInitializer::new(config_manager);

    (sut, file_path, base_dir)
}
```

and the caller would obtain the config_manager like this:

```
let (sut, file_path, base_dir) = prepare_sut_and_stuff();
let config_manager = &sut.config_manager;
```

This allows you to have clear ownership semantics.

If it is not possible to modify `ExistingProjectInitializer` to own the config manager, then it can be argued that the `prepare_sut_and_stuff()` is trying to do two different things:

1. Initialize a config manager
2. Initialize a project initializer

Even though having all in one place is certainly convenient, it might be clearer for the initialization of the ExistingProjectInitializer to happen outside of this function.

Answer (score 0):

Boxing the `AppConfigManager` seems to be the good intuition here, but the `ExistingProjectInitializer` you return references the box itself, not the `AppConfigManager` this box contains.

When the three result will be returned by value they will be moved, thus the reference to the box would become invalid (it's an error, and forbidden by the compiler).

If you want the `AppConfigManager` to be accessed by the `ExistingProjectInitializer` **as well as** by `config_manager` in the result, I think you need an `std::rc::Rc` instead of the box and [`clone()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html#impl-Clone) it inside the `ExistingProjectInitializer` (not a reference).

Maybe another solution would be to avoid to keeping multiple references to the same data (multiple references are difficult in Rust in general).
You could move (or store via a box) the `AppConfigManager` into the `ExistingProjectInitializer`, **not** return `config_manager` and give on `ExistingProjectInitializer` a way to access the `AppConfigManager` it contains whenever it's needed.

Here is a minimal example of the idea (as far as I understand the intent in the question).
`make_a_and_b()` returns two distinct structures, the first being also know from the second via an `Rc`.
`make_a_and_c()` simply returns a structure giving access to another structure it contains (much simpler in my opinion).

```rust
use expe::{A, B, C};
use std::rc::Rc;

pub fn make_a_and_b(value: i32) -> (Rc<A>, B) {
    let a = Rc::new(A::new(value));
    let b = B::new(a.clone());
    (a, b)
}

pub fn make_a_and_c(value: i32) -> C {
    let a = A::new(value);
    let c = C::new(a);
    c
}

fn main() {
    let (a, b) = make_a_and_b(123);
    println!("a contains {}", a.get_value());
    println!("b refers to a which contains {}", b.get_value());
    let c = make_a_and_c(456);
    println!("c contains a which contains {}", c.get_a().get_value());
}

mod expe {
    use std::rc::Rc;

    pub struct A {
        value: i32,
    }
    impl A {
        pub fn new(value: i32) -> Self {
            A { value }
        }
        pub fn get_value(&self) -> i32 {
            self.value
        }
    }

    pub struct B {
        a: Rc<A>,
    }
    impl B {
        pub fn new(a: Rc<A>) -> Self {
            B { a }
        }
        pub fn get_value(&self) -> i32 {
            self.a.value
        }
    }

    pub struct C {
        a: A,
    }
    impl C {
        pub fn new(a: A) -> Self {
            C { a }
        }
        pub fn get_a(&self) -> &A {
            &self.a
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show me how `Rc` could be used here? I can't manage to get it right. I end up with various kinds of errors. I wouldn't want to add a way to access `AppConfigManager` from the `ExistingProjectInitializer`, because this would be a bit "fake" interface. I only need it in the test for convenience.

Comment: @Loreno I tried to guess the context from your code and added a minimal example.